# MATLAB: Need to figure out how to apply some calculations in an if loop to each value of an array of 0:10:100

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement, matrix

I know I have to use a for loop of some sort but I'm not sure how. Basically I have an array of values 0:10:100, which correspond to exam test results. The first 60 marks are halved, the next 10 are left alone, and any marks above 70 are doubled. I managed to create a script to do this with a user inputted value:

```
module_mark = input('input number between 0 and 100: ');
if module_mark < 60
    exam_mark = module_mark/2
elseif module_mark > 60 && module_mark <= 70
    exam_mark = (module_mark-60)+30
elseif module_mark > 70 && module_mark <=100
    a = module_mark-60;
    if a < 10
    exam_mark = 30+a
    elseif a > 10
    exam_mark = 30+10+(module_mark-70)*2
    end
elseif module_mark > 100
    disp('error cannot get over 100')
end
```

I need to perform the same calculation but with the values of the array 0:10:100 instead of a user inputted value. I then need to put the outputted values into some sort of matrix so I can plot module marks against exam marks. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you are looking for:

```
myscores = 0:10:100;
output = zeros(1, length(myscores));
for ii = 1:length(myscores)
    mark = myscores(ii);
    if mark < 60
        output(ii) = mark / 2;
    elseif mark >= 60 && mark <= 70
        output(ii) = mark;
    elseif mark > 70
        output(ii) = mark * 2;
    else
        disp('error on mark= ')
        mark
    end
end

matrix_out = [myscores' output'];
```